# IoC (Castle Windsor) and Static Helpers

Tags: c#, static, extension-methods, castle-windsor

How do I configure Castle Windsor to use an `Initialize` method for a static helper class when requesting an object? I am trying to add some extension methods `HtmlHelper` so it has to be a static class and method. My `HtmlHelper` extensions depend on a `IHtmlHelpersService` that is configured with Castle Windsor already. I am using Convention Over Configuration.

**Edit**
I think what I want is a `ComponentActivator` or the `UsingFactory`. Am I going down a dead end that way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [Convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_Configuration)?

I don't know of any way to do what you suggest.  It's a bit hacky, but you could always create a class that is not static that conforms to the interface and simply executes the static methods you need it to.  Sometimes this type of thing is a necessary evil when using a third-party project.  Of course if you contributed the patch for static support to the Castle project, they may accept it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IoC can help you with static classes, Windsor (or any other IoC for that matter) need something it can instantiate (call a constructor).

Are you trying to swap out helper methods depending on configuration?
If so, maybe you could write a single set of extension methods that call the IoC for their implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, is to create a base class for all of your ViewPages.  Hide the existing HtmlHelper property with your own version:

```
public class MyHtmlHelper : HtmlHelper
{
  // Take helper service, implement special methods
}

public class MyViewPage : ViewPage
{
  protected new MyHtmlHelper HtmlHelper { get; set; }
  // Wire up HtmlHelper as appropriate -- which is not going to be easy since
  // the base property could be set at any time.
}
```

Now all your view pages will use your special MyHtmlHelper with all your special sauce, and they don't even need to be extension methods.  A variation is to have your MyHtmlHelper expose the service and continue to write extension methods that target that helper.

Answer (score -2):

You can refactor in this way taken from here http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ExistingApplications:

Adapt Static Class:

Sometimes an application will group related functionality into a class of static functions:

```
static class IdGenerator
{
  static int _next = 0;
  public static int GetNext()
  {
    return ++_next;
  }
}
```

This kind of design usually has no place in an application created using dependency injection.

Instead, create an interface that provides the same functionality:

```
interface IIdGenerator
{
  int GetNext();
}
```

And an implementing adapter class that uses the static methods:

```
class IdGeneratorAdapter : IdGenerator
{
  public int GetNext()
  {
    return IdGenerator.GetNext();
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not answer my question.